# JSF layout and templating

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a templating search.xhtml page to accept user's search term on the page. After the user click the "Search!" button, the result will be displayed on the same page, below the search box, as shown in the simple code below.

search.xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="search">
    <h:form id="wordForm">
            <h:inputText id="word" value="#{wordController.word}" />    
            <h:commandButton id="search" value="Search!"
                action="#{wordController.search}" />
    </h:form>
    </ui:define>

    /*** From here to display the search results!!! ***/
   <ui:define name="searchResult">      
    <h:outputText value="Search Results:"/>
    <c:forEach items="#{wordController.wordInfoList}" var="wordInfo">

        <h:outputText value="#{wordInfo.display}"
            rendered="#{not empty wordInfo.display}" /> 
         <ui:repeat value="#{wordInfo.relatedWords}" var="relatedInfo">
            <h:outputLink value="index.xhtml">
              <h:outputText value="#{relatedInfo}" />
              <f:param name="relatedWord" value="#{relatedInfo}" />
            </h:outputLink>
         </ui:repeat>
    </c:forEach>

/*Edit: Add a f:medatadata tag to accept the parameter "relatedWord" */
    <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam id="related" name="relatedWord"
                value="#{wordController.word}" />
            <f:viewAction action="#{wordController.info()}" />
    </f:metadata> 
</ui:define>
```

The layout.xhtml inserts the search.xhtml to the page.

layout.xhtml:

```
 <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty wordController.word}">
        <div id="searchResult">
            <ui:insert name="searchResult">                 
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

The problem is that, when the user visits the page, even before he clicks the "Search!" button, the search results will be always displayed together with teh search box, although the search result will be empty, except that the string "Search results: " is not empty.

How can I modify this so that before user performs a search, it will only display the search box. and only display the search results together with the search box after the user clicks the search button.

Thank you.

Comment: @BalusC, that's what I thought too. However, I don't want to print out "Search Results: " before user performs the search. Now, I added a function to indicate whether the search has been performed and added a <c:if> tag to the file. But it still doesn't work. After search, it doesn't print out the search result. Do you think the <c:if> tag make sense here?

Comment: @BalusC, please see the updated code. Why doesn't <ui:fragment> work for the <f:viewAction>? The "rendered="#{not empty wordnetController.word}" can prevent "Search results:" to be output before the user click the search button, but it doesn't prevent the "f:viewAction action=..." from being executed the first time the user visits the page, and hence haven't clicked the search button. The f:viewAction is also wrapped in the ui:fragment tag. Please help to understand this.